# Nokia NFC p2p message size

Tags: size, nokia, max, nfc

In Nokia NFC peer to peer mode (C7)
I want to know what is the maximum size for one message to be sent without partitioning in lower layers.
I knew that it is 248 byte in Android (from Log file).
But i can't find it in Nokia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NFC-IP1 protocol has a maximum packet size of 254 bytes. Anything larger will be at least broken down into two NFC-IP1 packets.

Comment: Is that mentioned in the NFC standards ??